# Regex searching and adding characters

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to use regex to add $ to the start of words in a string such that:

```
Answer = partOne + partTwo
```

becomes

```
$Answer = $partOne + $partTwo
```

I'm using `/ [a-z]/` to locate them but not sure what I'm meant to replace it with.

Is there anyway to do it with regex or am I suppose to just split up my string and put in the $?

I'm using perl right now.

Answer (score 2):

You can match word boundary `\b`, followed by word class `\w`

```
my $s = 'Answer = partOne + partTwo';

$s =~ s|\b (?= \w)|\$|xg;

print $s;
```

output

```
$Answer = $partOne + $partTwo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\w+)
```

You can use this.Replace by `\$$1`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/40

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lookahead to match only the space or start of a line anchor which was immediately followed by an alphabet. Replace the matched space character or starting anchor with a `$` symbol.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(my $line = <DATA>) {
    $line =~ s/(^|\s)(?=[A-Za-z])/$1\$/g;
    print $line;
}

__DATA__
Answer = partOne + partTwo
```

**Output:**

```
$Answer = $partOne + $partTwo
```

Comment: Your regex is a little clumsy as it insists that the word to be replace is preceded by whitespace or the start of the string, so it won't work for something like `Answer=partOne+partTwo`. You probably want a *word boundary* `\b`

Comment: no i don't need that. See the preceding character `(^|\s)`, already a word boundary is exits here. And also i posted this solution according to the op needs, see his regex / [a-z]/. And he was trying to add $ before a letter which was preceded by a space or start of the line anchor.

Comment: I'm saying that you should use `\b` *instead* of matching and copying a preceding space or start of string. Your substitution is best written `$line =~ s/\b(?=[A-Za-z])/\$/g`. The OP showed what he had tried that *wasn't working*, and it isn't necessary to duplicate it.

Comment: it matches the `\b`(which was before b,f) in `foo:bar`. So  what's wrong with providing an exact one?

Answer (score 0):

Perl's regexes have a *word* character class `\w` that is meant for exactly this sort of thing. It matches upper-case and lower-case letters, decimal digits, and the underscore `_`.

So if you prefix all ocurrences of one or more such characters with a dollar then it will achieve what you ask. It would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'Answer = partOne + partTwo';

$str =~ s/(\w+)/\$$1/g;

print $str, "\n";
```

**output**

```
$Answer = $partOne + $partTwo
```

But *please note* that, if the text you're processing is a programming language, this will also process all comments and string literals in a way you probably don't want.

Comment: is `\w` matches decimal digits?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Yes. It's the same as `[0-9A-Za-z_]`

Comment: But there isn't a dot in the above char class.

Comment: What if the user don't want to add a `$` before `_` symbol?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: If the string isn't a classic identifier then you can specify exactly what characters it contains with a bespoke character class like `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: @vks: You haven't posted a "solution"; what you wrote was `(\w+)` and commented that it *"can act as subtle hint"*. If you claim copyright on `(\w+)` then there are very many posts on SO that you can complain about.

Comment: @Borodin its not about copyright.Its about not cluttering SO with similar answers :)

Comment: @vks Borodin's answer may come from the same principle, but it explains things arguably better. There is nothing wrong with that at all.